# Why is my filter function not working within rShiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny

Each time I try to run my rShiny app, it doesn't give me an error, but my plot won't show up all the way. I know it has to do with my filter, because I added an output to see the table I'm filtering, and it is empty.

It is showing the border and some labels but, the graph itself is not showing up, along with the empty table. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6p4w.png) is what my webapp looks like.

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel('NFL Draft'),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      
      checkboxGroupInput('seasons', 'Seasons:',
                         choices = c('2004' = 1,
                                     '2005' = 2,
                                     '2006' = 3,
                                     '2007' = 4,
                                     '2008' = 5,
                                     '2009' = 6,
                                     '2010' = 7,
                                     '2011' = 8,
                                     '2012' = 9,
                                     '2013' = 10,
                                     '2014' = 11,
                                     '2015' = 12,
                                     '2016' = 13),
                         selected = c(1,2,3,4,5)),
      checkboxGroupInput('positions', 'Positions:',
                         choices = c('QB' = 1,
                                     'TE' = 2,
                                     'WR' = 3,
                                     'RB' = 4,
                                     'FB' = 5),
                         selected = 1)),
    mainPanel(
      
      plotOutput('epa_by_draft'),
      tableOutput('table')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  position.x = c('QB', 'QB', 'QB', 'RB', 'RB', 'WR', 'WR', 'TE', 'FB', 'FB', 'WR', 'TE', 'TE', 'QB', 'QB')
  season.y = c(2012, 2010, 2004, 2004, 2010, 2005, 2007, 2006, 2008, 2009, 2011, 2014, 2013, 2015, 2016)
  round = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1)
  total_epa = c(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0)
  draft_epa = data.frame(position.x, season.y, round, total_epa)
  filtered_draft_epa = reactive({draft_epa %>%
      filter(position.x %in% input$positions & season.y %in% input$seasons)})
  
  output$table = renderTable({
    print(filtered_draft_epa())
  })
  
  output$epa_by_draft = renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered_draft_epa(), aes(x = season.y,
                          y = round,
                          fill = total_epa))+geom_tile()+
    scale_fill_gradient(high = 'green', low = 'red', limits = c(floor(-3), ceiling(3)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am trying to create a rShiny app with two checkbox filter widgets that allow the user to choose any combination of years or position for an "EPA by draft round" heat map that should show up in the main panel.

Instead of giving me this when I run the code, I get everything except for the plotted portion of the heat map, which has something to do with my filter function.

Edit: updated code to be reproducable

Comment: From the description of your issue I would guess that your code returns a dataset with no obs or zero rows. But without [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data to actually run your code one can not even guess what might be the issue .

Comment: Updated code to be reproducible, thanks @stefan

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that have set your `choices` to numbers 1, 2, 3, ... whereas the categories in your data are years i.e. `2008`, `2009`, ... and player position i.e. `"QB"`, `"WR"`, ... Hence, you always get an empty dataset after filtering. Simply use the categories from your data for the `choices` argument to fix your issue:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("NFL Draft"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("seasons", "Seasons:",
        choices = 2004:2016,
        selected = 2004:2008
      ),
      checkboxGroupInput("positions", "Positions:",
        choices = c(
          "QB",
          "TE",
          "WR",
          "RB",
          "FB"
        ),
        selected = c("QB", "WR")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("epa_by_draft"),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  position.x <- c("QB", "QB", "QB", "RB", "RB", "WR", "WR", "TE", "FB", "FB", "WR", "TE", "TE", "QB", "QB")
  season.y <- c(2012, 2010, 2004, 2004, 2010, 2005, 2007, 2006, 2008, 2009, 2011, 2014, 2013, 2015, 2016)
  round <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1)
  total_epa <- c(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0)
  draft_epa <- data.frame(position.x, season.y, round, total_epa)
  filtered_draft_epa <- reactive({
    draft_epa %>%
      filter(position.x %in% input$positions & season.y %in% input$seasons)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    print(filtered_draft_epa())
  })

  output$epa_by_draft <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered_draft_epa(), aes(
      x = season.y,
      y = round,
      fill = total_epa
    )) +
      geom_tile() +
      scale_fill_gradient(high = "green", low = "red", limits = c(floor(-3), ceiling(3)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7087
#>   position.x season.y round total_epa
#> 1         QB     2004     3        -1
#> 2         WR     2005     6         2
#> 3         WR     2007     7         3
```

[image]